# Invalid data helpme

Tags: java

I'm trying to parse through my code so I can edit the invalid data to something like "Data is invalid." I'm having trouble getting the splitter to work out.

Word One - Word Two - Word Three - Word Four - Word Five
Is there an easier way to do this rather than going sorting each individual token into arrays. So where the "-" is attached to a word, I'd like advice on how to change this and display something like "Invalid Data"

Comment: *the example invalidvalid data is* - is that valid or invalid? Can you re-explain what should and should not be accepted?

Comment: The example data is both invalid and valid. So the third line would be a valid line, but line one would be invalid.

Comment: So if it has a `-` without leading and trailing spaces, it's invalid?

Comment: Yeah, that would be invalid.

Comment: how about making a check on the length of `words` ?
Also, what exactly do u want to do with invalid data?

Comment: I'm no expert - but a `regex` might help.

Comment: I just want the invalid data to be changed so it prints out something like "Title may be invalid" or "Price may be invalid"

Comment: How do I use a regex? I'm new to java, sorry.

Comment: My regex knowledge isn't good enough to give you a solution. Perhaps someone else can help you with this.

Answer (score 2):

Just split around the "-" since that is how the data is being separated. Whenever you get a space as an index in your array then you know the data doesn't contain that data. Try this where you check that the data is not a whitespace or the data matches a digit.

```
  while(read.hasNextLine())
  {
      line = read.nextLine();
      String[] words = line.split("-");
      if(words.length == 5)
      {
          Title[counter] = words[0].matches("\\s+") ? "No Title" : words[0];
          Author[counter] = words[1].matches("\\s+") ? "No Author" : words[1];
          Price[counter] = !words[2].matches("\\d+") ? 0 : Integer.parseInt(words[2]);
          Publisher[counter] = words[3].matches("\\s+") ? "No Publisher" : words[3];
          ISBN[counter] = !words[4].matches("\\d+") ? 0 : Integer.parseInt(words[4]);
          System.out.println(Title[counter] + Author[counter] + Price[counter] + Publisher[counter] + ISBN[counter]);
          counter++;
      }
      else
      {
          System.out.println("Invalid Data format: " + line);
      }
  }
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for this! It helps, but then this gives me a type mismatch error on the `"No Price"` and `"No ISBN"` parts, any way to resolve this?

Comment: If you want to have `"Price may be invalid"` when price is invalid, u have to change ur datatype for price to `String`

Comment: I changed it to set the default value of invalid ISBN and Prices to 0 since they are integers, sorry for the error @HelpMe

Comment: @HelpMe before the edits you had a name like *Joe-Bloggs*. Is this valid or invalid? Just in case you split by dash or similar method, this part may fail.