# Reading in file - input missing

Tags: java, file

I was trying to help [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47396345/how-can-i-change-ignore-invalid-string-data-from-a-text-file-java) user with an answer, but reading in the file isn't working as I expected.

If I create a file with just the OPs first two lines:

> Learning Java - William Lane -12.00 - Wiley - 0811234561
>
> - William Stalling - 25.00 - Prentice Hall - 1304086641

The output is as expected:

```
Learning Java - William Lane -12.00 - Wiley - 0811234561
- William Stalling - 25.00 - Prentice Hall - 1304086641
```

But when I add the third line:

> Learning Java - William Lane -12.00 - Wiley - 0811234561
>
> - William Stalling - 25.00 - Prentice Hall - 1304086641
>
> OOP programming - Graham Winter - 32.50 – O'Reilly - 0471974555

The output is blank.

My code is straight forward, just to test it. I copied and pasted the file contents directly from the linked question above. Is there a special character on that line, and if so, how to find it? And why would it not print the other lines?

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("myfile"));
        while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
            String nameLine = sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println(nameLine);
        }
```

I ran it through a debugger and `sc.hasNextLine` returns `false` and the program ends.

**Edit:**

I'm using `Notepad` basically to test this, and noticed (on the browser) that the dash between 32.50 and O'Reilly is slightly elongated. So I removed this dash and saved and the program works as expected. When I put it back in and save and re-run the program, it doesn't display anything. I can produce this every time.

I then tested in `Notepad++` and all worked smoothly. Happy days.

So I did a comparison between the two files with `WinMerge`; it basically says the only difference is that dash, and on `Notepad++`, it's `â€“` but on `Notepad`, it's `–`.

Anyone any ideas?

Comment: if you have java 8 or above available have a look at https://www.mkyong.com/java8/java-8-stream-read-a-file-line-by-line/

Comment: And you are sure that the version of the filr that is accessed really has those lines in it?

Comment: i tested it and for me it works fine .. do your programm maybe throw an exception?

Comment: No exception thrown; just basically saying no next line so program ends happily with no print statement. @Lino - yes it does, i.e. I put the first two lines in the file, save, close, run program, output is the two lines. Open the text file, add the third line, save, close, run program, output is blank :-|

Comment: What happens if you remove all content from file?

Comment: It will just print nothing @m0skit0

Comment: The name of your file is "MyFile"? No extension? Make sure the file path is true.

Comment: @notyou Did you actually test it?

Comment: It never gave an error. kindly copy the contents from notepad to notepad++ and then do a winmerge with file format set to windows and utf-8

Answer (score 0):

THis might probably because of difference in file encoding/character set. Try reading the file as UTF-8 mode and check.

Comment: Yes, this seems partly of what may be the issue; however my main question is *why* won't it read any of the file if it does contain `–`.

Comment: could you share your file, i couldn't reproduce the issue.

Answer (score -1):

You may try these changes to see if it works for you. In your post i copied your 3 lines put it to notepad and saved and then opened in notepad++. It never gave issue.[image]

Comment: Did you read the edit? I know how to read in a file, it just turns out using Notepad seemed to be the problem.

Comment: Its got to do with the unicode characters. More about it is found [here](https://unicode-table.com/en/). You can copy the content to an intermediate editor before even saving it as is. Because sometimes the source from which you copy might use a different symbols that in your current environment is mapped to a different symbol. Eg: Source ->Notepad->Notepad++. You can also check out other answer to see if it helps.