# Unable to read any of file that contains specific character(s)

Tags: java, file, character-encoding

**TL;DR**

Why does reading in a file with `–` not find *any* data on `Notepad`?

**Problem:**

Up to this point, I have been using just plain ol' `Notepad` (Version 6.1) to read/write text for testing/answering questions here.

Simple bit of code to read in the text files contents, and print them to the console:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("myfile.txt"));
while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
    String text = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println(text);
}
```

All is well, the lines print as expected.

Then, if I put in this *exact* character: `–`, anywhere in the text file, it will not read any of the file, and print nothing to the console.

I can of course use `Notepad++` or other (better) text editors, and there is no issue, the text, including the dash character, will print as expected.

I can also specify `UTF-8`, using `Notepad`, and it will work fine:

```
File fileDir = new File("myfile.txt");
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(
               new FileInputStream(fileDir), "UTF8"));
String str;
while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
       System.out.println(str);
}
```

On my original `Notepad` file, if I copy and paste the text (including the `–`) into `Notepad++` and compare the two files with `WinMerge`, it tells me that the dash on `Notepad` is `–`, but on `Notepad++`, it is `â€“`.

**Question:**

Why, when this `–` is used in a text file in `Notepad`, it reads *nothing*, basically telling me that `hasNextLine()` is false? Should it not at least read the input until the line that contains this specific character?

**Steps to reproduce:**

- On Windows 7, right-click and create new Text Document.
- Put any text in the file (without any special characters, as such)
- Put in this character anywhere in the file: `–`
- Run the first block of code above

Output: `BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)`, i.e. doesn't print *any* of the text.

**PS:**

I know I asked a similar (well, it ended up being the same) [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47397264/reading-in-file-input-missing?noredirect=1#comment81752895_47397264) yesterday, but unfortunately, it seems I may not have explained myself well, or some of the viewers didn't fully read the question. Either way, I think I've explained it better here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue seems to be a difference of encoding. You have to read in the same encoding that the file was written into.

Your system notepad probably uses [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252)(or Cp-1252) encoding. There have been problems in this encoding with a range of characters between 128 - 159. The Dash lies between this range. This range is not present in the equivalent ISO 8859-1, and is only present in the Cp1252 encoding.

[image]

Eclipse, when reading the notepad file, assumes the file to be having the encoding ISO-8859-1 (as it is equivalent). But this character is not present in ISO-8859-1, hence the problem. If you want to read from Java, you will have to specify Cp1252, and you should get your output.

This is also the reason why your code with UTF-8 works correctly, when the file in notepad is written in UTF-8.

Comment: Hmm ok, I see what you mean. Why would it not read *any* text then? Should it not read the lines until that specific character?

Comment: I am not really sure of that. Probably because you are using Scanner class, which parses the input first. You could try with BufferedReader

Comment: You could try getting the bytes and checking them if Java really reads the file - Files.readAllBytes(Path).

Answer (score 0):

A buffered reader reads more than the current line, maybe the text upto the problematic bytes. [Charset.CharsetDecoder.onMalformedInput](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/CharsetDecoder.html#onMalformedInput-java.nio.charset.CodingErrorAction-) then comes in play, and there something restricive happens, which I would normally not have expected.

Do you use a special JDK? Do you wipe exceptions under the carpet? Like a lambda wrapping the above code. (Add catch Throwable)

Is your platfom encoding `-Dfile.encoding=ISO-8859-1` instead of `Cp1252`.

Comment: I'm throwing a few exceptions, including `UnsupportedEncodingException` but they aren't caught. Nothing special going on here, as far as I can tell. Also - I was reading your two comments, and was in the process of replying but you removed them :)

Comment: Sorry, the comments were not very good, I still did not drink my first coffee, and a third long winded comment was a bit too much, hence this mediocre answer instead. You tried both encodings. Notepad++ is a good tool for testing encodings.